# Xcode4 best practice: English xib/nib updated. How to continue?

Tags: localization, xcode4

i am currently updating a project, where I have already implemented certain new features into the english xibs, but now I of course have to also update the localized versions of my nibs/xibs. Is there any best practice to do that?

My normal workflow would be to manually add the changed controls and then localize them, or maybe even throw all localized versions away and start localizing from scratch. But thats a pain in the ... whatever and I guess that there must be a less time consuming way.

Any suggestions? :-)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the localized nibs using ibtool. To do it you need to keep a copy of the pervious version of the pervious version of the english nib.  I usually just grab a copy of it out of git or svn when I go to do the localization.  The following command will update the french version MyNib with the changes you've made to the english version with the assumption that you've in the directory that holds the lproj folders.

```
ibtool  --previous-file en.lproj/MyNibOld.xib --incremental-file fr.lproj/MyNib.xib --localize-incremental --write fr.lproj/MyNib.xib en.lproj/MyNib.xib
```

after running that, you just need to edit the nib to change any of the new strings to french and to verify that the geometry of the new items is good.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I really wonder why Apple don't integrates that into the GUI?

Comment: 2011-04-28 20:30:47.699 ibtoold[4987:107] [MT] ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-1306/CocoaIntegration/WidgetIntegration/SegmentedControl/IBNSSegmentedControlIntegration.m:283
Details:  Wrong Number Of Items
Object:   <NSSegmentedCell: 0x2007fefe0>
Method:   -setIbShadowedLabels:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x20000fdc0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Any Idea what might be wrong? :-(

Comment: I've never received that one before. Maybe you entered the previous and new english nibs backwards or crossed up the languages. Those are complete guesses though since I've never encountered that error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the issue once of the ASSERTION FAILURE from the above answer. Right clicking on my project file and doing "Show Package Contents" then deleting my User data folder and Workspace file did the trick. Be sure to take a backup of your project file first though in case you need anything from it.